# Subclassing NSString in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

if I have a class like

```
@interface myclass:NSString
   {
       double b;
   }
```

now if I want to change both the value b and string value of myclass, how should I proceed after alloc init?

Comment: You probably want to build a new class that *has* a double and a NSString, not one that *is* an NSString.

Comment: I've given an example of Eiko's suggesting in my answer below.

Comment: Are you the same user as http://stackoverflow.com/users/872302/user872302? If not, could you explain briefly why you have the same IP address and is posting similar questions?

Answer (score 7):

Note, it's not a good idea to subclass NSString.

NSString is not actually such a simple class. And it shouldn't be subclassed without a good reason.

For NSString it is much better to add methods through [Categories](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1) or object composition.

But note, adding an ivar in a category is not allowed.
You can add properties, though, and use [associative references](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html) in Objective-C 2.0 to access this private data.

There's a good note about subclassing NSStrings right in [NSString class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html):

> It is possible to subclass NSString (and NSMutableString), but doing
>   so requires providing storage facilities for the string (which is not
>   inherited by subclasses) and implementing two primitive methods. The
>   abstract NSString and NSMutableString classes are the public interface
>   of a class cluster consisting mostly of private, concrete classes that
>   create and return a string object appropriate for a given situation.
>   Making your own concrete subclass of this cluster imposes certain
>   requirements (discussed in “Methods to Override”).
>
> Make sure your reasons for subclassing NSString are valid. Instances
>   of your subclass should represent a string and not something else.
>   Thus the only attributes the subclass should have are the length of
>   the character buffer it’s managing and access to individual characters
>   in the buffer. Valid reasons for making a subclass of NSString include
>   providing a different backing store (perhaps for better performance)
>   or implementing some aspect of object behavior differently, such as
>   memory management. If your purpose is to add non-essential attributes
>   or metadata to your subclass of NSString, a better alternative would
>   be object composition (see “Alternatives to Subclassing”). Cocoa
>   already provides an example of this with the NSAttributedString class.

And on the bottom of the class reference there's another section on NSString subclassing alternatives.

Comment: Note that in recent runtimes and compilers, it *is* possible to add properties (and their memory). Still I wouldn't do it as it would bloat *every* instance of an NSString. Subclassing NSString is probably not what makes the most sense here, though. :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to expose your new double as a property like so:

```
@interface MyClass : NSString
{
    double b;
}

@property double b;

@end
```

then in the .m file:

```
@implementation MyClass

@synthesize b;

@end
```

then when you create an instance, you can access the double property:

```
MyClass* myClassInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
myClassInstance.b = 1.2;
```

**EDIT**: *The above won't work! See Jacob's answer as to why...*

As a consolation prize, here's a wrapper class that will give you a String & Double

```
@interface MyString : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* string;
@property double b;

- (id)initWithString:(NSString *)aString andDouble:(double)aDouble;

@end
```

and implementation

```
@implementation MyString

@synthesize string, b;

- (id)initWithString:(NSString *)aString andDouble:(double)aDouble
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.string = aString;
        self.b = aDouble;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [string release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: in this way i give value to b

Comment: but how to give value to the string of my class. I can not call initWithString over this class as NSString is a abstract parent of class cluster

Comment: I stand corrected... you can't add storage to an existing class! You'll have to write a wrapper class.

Comment: I've added a wrapper that will give you an NSString + Double in one class.

Answer (score 1):

Jacob Gorban's answer is correct: you probably don't need to subclass the string. In terms of storing extra data, you might consider using [`objc_setAssociatedObject`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_setAssociatedObject).

Answer (score 0):

You could see my example with NSString subclassing here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/21331422/1891772

PS. Use it only in case when it's necessary to subclass NSString and you can't use wrappers